# Opensearch serverless dashboard giving unauthorization error

Tags: collections, serverless, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have created a serverless opensearch collection using terraform. When I click on OpenSearch Dashboards URL, it's giving below error.

"You don’t have authorization to access dashboards. Please configure data and network policy.
Please contact AWS Support for any assistance."

The dashboard is set as public.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you get to resolve this?